# How to retrieve partial S3 object values by key

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

Given an S3 bucket called `my-bucket` that includes a bucket with key named `my-object`, is it possible to retrieve values from the object if the object value consists of a list of key/value pairs?

i.e. if `my-object` contains a file with the following key/value pairs:

```
foo: 20, 
bar: 54, 
baz: 12
```

Is it possible to just retrieve the value of 'foo' by its key using the SDK for Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Amazon S3 Select](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/04/amazon-s3-select-is-now-generally-available/) to parse the values.

However, the format of your file isn't great because:

- Some lines have a comma, others do not
- It has excess spaces in the file

Let's say you had this format instead:

```
foo:20
bar:54
baz:12
```

You could then query it with **S3 Select**, using the colon as a separator:

---

[image: Amazon S3 Select]

---

To do this in Java, see: [Selecting Content from Objects Using the SDK for Java - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SelectObjectContentUsingJava.html)